# How do you right-align text into a column?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to shove a paragraph on my page to the very right like it is in this image: [image: Right-Align]

I want a large, left-aligned title with a small right-aligned paragraph on a page. So far, I can't get the CSS make it look anything like this but I'm guessing it isn't too difficult.  Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

CSS:

```
.rectangle-container .title {
color: $white;
margin: 0 .5em;
padding: 1em 0 0 3em;
font-family: OpenSans, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rectangle-container p {
    color: $white;
    text-align: right;
}
```

.rectangle-container .title is my title and naturally left-aligns, but .rectangle-container p comes up seemingly right-aligned, however it doesn't stack the text at all and ends up spanning the entire page.

Comment: can you show the CSS you have used so far?

Comment: @Martin He wants the whole block aligned right, not just the text flow. It looks like he wants to align a column of `justified` text to the right of a div.

Comment: Do you know the width of the text block you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with left side margin on your text `<p>` block.

So you set your text to be justified, and right align the whole block with a large left side gap, which combined with the width of the text fills the container.

```
.rectangle-container p {
color: $white;
text-align:justified;
width:70%;
margin-left:30%;
padding:0;
}
```

I would think that using `padding` would not work as well as by default padding is contained within the `width` attribute, whereas `margin` is outside the width. If the above example is substituted padding for margin, the padding would be a percentage of the 30% width, which would be clearly incorrect.

**Notes:**

- This solution works as long as `Width + margin + padding + border = 100%` of container. So if down the line you add a padding or a border then you should adjust the other values accordingly. Browsers will accept these values but occasional browser behaviour can be a bit unexpected if the sum of these elements is above 100% width of the container box.
- As a general guide try to avoid odd number values for percentage widths.
- You can use CSS3 `calc();` values to get dynamic values for the `p` elements content `width` CSS.

Comment: I have added some notes to my answer for you @chadb768 . Hope that helps too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just set the left `padding` of the paragraph to however much you want to "indent" by, be that a fixed size or, as in the following example, a percentage.

```css
h1,p{
    font-family:arial;
    margin:0;
}
p{
    text-align:justify;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris faucibus, enim quis venenatis mattis, felis libero consequat leo, sed feugiat orci eros ac felis. Donec elementum, lacus vel malesuada tincidunt, nisl massa consequat sem, at convallis urna nisl at enim ...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Style the div containing the paragraph or the paragraph itself with

Style="float:right"

Comment: If it `floats` then it will overlap with the title as it would begin directly on the right hand side of the title text, which would be incorrect as it should appear underneath it. float is not the answer here.

Comment: Put the paragraph inside a div and it will be below the h1

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want your text block aligned right with justified text, which can be done using `absolute` positioning.

You need a set up in your html like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <h1>Your Title</h1>
        <p><!-- your text here --></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

followed by the css to position the elements, pay close attention to the way the `<p>` div is positioned.

```
.parent{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background:red;
    height:100vh;
}

.child{
    width:700px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background:aliceblue;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h1{
    text-align:left;
}

p{
      text-align: justify;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;

}
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0q48pLsz/)** that will show you what it will look like.

Comment: absolute positioning seems to be a bit of an overkill when margins and width values (as in my answer) seem to do what's needed.

Comment: Everyone has their tastes, I find it's easier for me to work with positioning for responsive, so I prefer to use solutions like mine over having `25%` on a `padding-right` and etc..

Comment: To be honest, I do see your point of view, I don't use Absolute positioning much (as it is a pain to apply dynamically) but percentages is by no means the only way of doing this.

Comment: Without making too much of a biased case, I went to school for Graphic Design where we learned a slight amount of html/css, just enough to make a portfolio website. I however self taught myself responsive and more advanced positioning things, so it's just what I'm used to. I'm not great at math either so I'll avoid counting percents any chance I can  lol

Comment: We both have different ways of solving the problem, and that's one of the beauties of StackOverflow - although I have picked up in general that using `relative` and `absolute` positioning does make things work but in a rather non-dynamic way, that CSS things do not naturally adjust to different screen sizes (extra narrow etc.). But that's beyond the scope of the OP questions.

Comment: Exactly, when I answered mine, he only had the image and no css. Although you could make my solution responsive, I just generally assumed it wasn't. Had he had example code that showed it was meant to respond to certain sizes, my answer may have been aimed more towards percent padding.